# Flume ScribeSource, how to set Thrift Frame Size?

Tags: flume, scribe

I am trying to get Flume work with scribe, using ScribeSource, getting the following Exception and flume stops receiving data in few minutes, (roughly 1 mb in a second).

Is there any way I can set Frame Size on Flume, so that it can accept the scribe traffic. Constraint would be not to change it on Scribe side...

```
2014-06-10 19:40:40,405 WARN org.apache.thrift.server.THsHaServer: Exception while invoking!
org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: Frame size (23757404) larger than max length (16384000)!
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TFramedTransport.readFrame(TFramedTransport.java:137)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TFramedTransport.read(TFramedTransport.java:101)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransport.readAll(TTransport.java:84)
    at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readAll(TBinaryProtocol.java:378)
    at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readI32(TBinaryProtocol.java:297)
    at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readMessageBegin(TBinaryProtocol.java:204)
    at org.apache.thrift.TBaseProcessor.process(TBaseProcessor.java:27)
    at org.apache.thrift.server.AbstractNonblockingServer$FrameBuffer.invoke(AbstractNonblockingServer.java:478)
    at org.apache.thrift.server.Invocation.run(Invocation.java:18)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is caused due to Flume scribe source using TFrameTransport.Factory() which creates with default value 16MB.

If ScribeSource uses TFramedTransport.Factory(thriftFrameSize), then this would be resolved...

```
//Added to accept custom frame size
private int thriftFrameSize = DEFAULT_THRIFT_FRAME_SIZE;

private SourceCounter sourceCounter;

@Override
public void configure(Context context) {
  port = context.getInteger("port", port);

  workers = context.getInteger("workerThreads", DEFAULT_WORKERS);
  if (workers <= 0) {
    workers = DEFAULT_WORKERS;
  }

  if (sourceCounter == null) {
    sourceCounter = new SourceCounter(getName());
  }

  thriftFrameSize = context.getInteger("thriftFrameSize", DEFAULT_THRIFT_FRAME_SIZE);
  if (thriftFrameSize <= 0) {
     thriftFrameSize = DEFAULT_THRIFT_FRAME_SIZE;
  }
}

private class Startup extends Thread {

  public void run() {
    try {
      Scribe.Processor processor = new Scribe.Processor(new Receiver());
      TNonblockingServerTransport transport = new TNonblockingServerSocket(port);
      THsHaServer.Args args = new THsHaServer.Args(transport);

      args.workerThreads(workers);
      args.processor(processor);
      args.transportFactory(new TFramedTransport.Factory(thriftFrameSize));
```